# Tabular type used with "in" condition

Tags: azure-application-insights, azure-log-analytics

How can I use a tabular type in an `in` conditional statement?  See the last condition in the second query below: `Computer in clusterNodes`.  I get the following syntax error:

> Query could not be parsed at 'in' on line [9,181]
>
> Token: in Line: 9 Position: 181

```
let clusterNodes = 
KubeNodeInventory
| where TimeGenerated > ago(7d)
| where ClusterName == "test-aks"
| distinct Computer;

Perf
| where TimeGenerated > ago(1d) 
| where CounterName == "cpuUsageNanoCores" and ObjectName == "K8SNode" and Computer in clusterNodes 
| summarize ValueAvg = avg(CounterValue) by Time = bin(TimeGenerated, 15m), Counter = CounterName
| project round(ValueAvg / 1000000000, 2), Time, Counter 
| render timechart;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should help to leverage ***in*** in this scenario:

```
| where … and Computer in (clusterNodes)
```

P.S. You may also need to remove an empty row between ***let*** and the rest of the query (depending on how you select the query in UI to execute).